# Writing data in CSV stops even script is running

Tags: php, debugging, csv

I have PHP script for scrap and  writes huge data in CSV file. It's working but after writing some data in CSV it stops writing without showing any error on screen. But browser shows script running continuously.

I have set the time limit for php script infinite using `set_time_limit(0)`

How can I debug for this issue? What possible reason can be there?  Please suggest.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Once thing I have noted, it stops writing after 1 hr.

Comment: Safemode off? Error reporting on? And perhaps try to set the limit within the loop - to a smaller value - like 10. Did work for me.

Comment: What about the php error log?

Comment: Hi, I have checked log some warning message for initialization are there but nothing such that can stop writing.

Answer (score 1):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Your script is probally allocating too much memory. You may try to write just a small CSV. If it also fails, you should get an error...

Comment: increased memory limit. but still not working. Once thing I noted it stops writing after 1 hr.

Comment: Have tested it with a small cvs?